# get today's imported data from mongodb using timestamp node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, timestamp, momentjs

I add reports into a MongoDB database by current timestamp but I am not able to retrieve today's imported data because the current timestamp is different from the timestamp's value of inserted data. how can I see data by using timestamp?

add reprots

```
reportsController.addReports = function (req, resp) {


    let battriesObjs = [];
    let banksObjs = [];
    let reports = req.body;

    // console.log(batteries);


    const siteReports = new SiteReports({
        siteId: reports.siteId,
        environmentParam1: reports.envp1,
        environmentParam2: reports.envp2,
        environmentParam3: reports.envp3,
        reportDate: moment().valueOf()
    });


    let btr = reports['battries'];
    btr.forEach(function (btry) {
        const batteryReports = new BatteryReports({
            batteryId: btry.bid,
            batteryStatus: btry.status,
            batteryVoltage: btry.voltage,
            batteryTemperature: btry.temperature,
            reportDate: moment().valueOf()
        });

        battriesObjs.push(batteryReports);
    });


    siteReports
        .save()
        .then(value => {
            console.log("insert sampleCollection result ", value);
            BatteryReports
                .insertMany(battriesObjs)
                .then(valueBatteries =>
                    resp.status(status.OK)
                        .json({'respond': 'the document is updated successfully'}))
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("bulk insert sampleCollection error ", err);

                });

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("bulk insert sampleCollection error ", err);
        });


};
```

get reprots

```
reportsController.getAllTodayBatteryReports = function (req, resp) {

    console.log(req.query.batteryBankId, moment().valueOf());
    BatteryReports.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {

                "reportDate": moment().valueOf().toString()
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "batteryschemas",
                    localField: "batteryId",
                    foreignField: "batteryId",
                    as: "batteryReports_with_their_info"
                }
        }
        ,
        {
            $match:
                {"batteryReports_with_their_info.batteryBankId": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.batteryBankId)}

        }
        ,
        {
            $replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$batteryReports_with_their_info", 0]}, "$$ROOT"]}}
        }
        ,
        {
            $project: {
                batteryReports_with_their_info: 0,
                batteryBrand: 0,
                batteryMaximumChargingCurrent: 0,
                batteryCycleOfCharge: 0,
                batteryModel: 0,
                batteryProductDate: 0,
                batteryInternalResistance: 0,
                batteryCapacity: 0,
                __v: 0
            }
        }


    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err) {
            resp.status(status.NOT_FOUND).json({'respond': err + ''});
        } else {

            resp.status(status.OK).json(result);
        }
        // console.log(result);
    });
};
```

As you see this part of my code get the current timestamp and put it to the MongoDB match method but although some data were added in today's timestamp, I cannot get these records by current timestamp value.

```
$match: {
              "reportDate": moment().valueOf().toString()
        }
```

samples

```
 {
        "_id": "5d3c9116ee51fe32b44160f6",
        "batteryId": "1",
        "batteryVoltage": "5.5",
        "batteryVoltageMin": "34",
        "batteryVoltageMax": "34",
        "batteryMinTemperature": "443",
        "batteryMaxTemperature": "43",
        "batteryBankId": "5d29c1469e0e8b3afcf3a1e6",
        "batteryStatus": "H",
        "batteryTemperature": "38",
        "reportDate": "1564250390757"
    }
```

Comment: please provide sample documents

Comment: @srinivasy I added a sample

Comment: that's a string, So can you try range queries and let me know if it's feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `moment().valueOf()` value to an object and use it against reportDate. Plus `moment().valueOf()` will give you timestamp in milliseconds then inserted time will be different to querying time, So you need to do a range query in order to get specific records/documents or else pass exact timestamp to get exact match.

let's say you've inserted few documents today, and wanted to run your query at a given timestamp on the same day(be mindful of timestamps are of same zone) then,

```
let currentTimeStamp = moment().valueOf().toString()
let startOfDayTimeStamp = moment().startOf('day').valueOf().toString()
```

then,

```
$match: {
              "reportDate": { $gt: startOfDayTimeStamp, $lt: currentTimeStamp }
        }
```

If you're dealing with collection which has frequent writes, then you're dealing with high amounts of data for read query like this, just keep in mind to do proper indexing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked when i added .toString(). please add .toString() to your answer

Comment: yes, it will work when you add .toString() cause mongoDB will take it as string not an int as value of reportDate is not suitable for int due to length, then while querying as well you need to make it a string and query against saved documents as reportDate is a string in DB..!!